# Java: alternate keyboard suport

Tags: java, keyboard, keylistener

I use a Dvorak keyboard, and it gets rather annoying to swap between keyboards to test my code. I've noticed that some games like anything by Bethesda, Minecraft (1.13+), and Fallout 1 allow you to use alternate keyboards without rebinding all of the keys (ie they auto rebind, listen to the position of key on the keyboard,or something along those lines) so I was wondering how to do that with java, preferably in a way that also allows you to still rebind the keys.The code below is what I currently use to have inputs, but I don't know how to make it listen to different things for different keyboard layouts.

```
    public class KeyInput extends KeyAdapter{
    
    
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
    int key = e.getKeyCode();
    
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_EXAMPLEKEY) exampleFunction();
    
    }
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to implement this into a Java GUI application or for general usage on your computer?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but I'm using it in a Jframe and a game that I am making

Comment: Then all you would need to do is set up a key listener in your program. Right? Or I might be misunderstanding your question.

Comment: That's what I already do, but I use keyPressed and keyReleased and test what Keyevent e.getKeyCode() is. I want to know if there is a way that will, no matter which keyboard I use, have the same key in the same position give the same output. IE, g in qwerty is i on dvorak, but if I press the "g" key on either I want it to output the same thing.